# Light attenuation through water at an angle

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, mathematical-physics, mathematical-modeling

I know that light intensity decreases exponentially governed by 
\begin{equation*}
\frac{dy}{dx} = -ky 
\end{equation*}
where $y$ is the intensity and $x$ is the distance.

Now what happens when light strikes down at an angle ? Suppose at $45^\circ$ through water.

Comment: After the light ray enters water, the angle is forgotten and has no meaning.

Comment: So this same differential equation will govern the intensity ? And what about Beer-Lambert Law ? Will they play any roll here ?

Comment: Think about it - how can the angle possibly matter once the light crosses the boundary and enters the substance? I don't remember Beer's law clearly, is that the one which deals with attenuation coefficient? Yeah then it probably plays a role in determining $k$. Has nothing to do with angle though.

Comment: The light reflects and refracts as it enters the water. This makes a significant difference when we consider different angles. However, after the interface is crossed, it goes on as if it was always wet.

Answer (score 0):

Beer-Lambert's formula as expressed above holds if you consider $x$ to be the distance measured along the path of the ray.
If your ray is moving along different straight segments (i.e. in various homogeneous mediums), the easiest is to set your axes so that the ray moves along the $Ox$ axis for each straight segment.